# Navigation Drawer Android best practice

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am looking for advice on navigation pattern in android. In the current state of the app i am working at, I have a navigation drawer and can access some elements that are mostly dynamically changed. When I click an item from the navigation drawer I show a fragment. So anytime i want i go back to the left menu. Now, i have to move "New screen" activity from picture, in the same pattern, to have access to the drawer. The only way to get to "New screen" activity is from one of the fragments.

Fragment 0 has a list of items. Clicking on it it opens the "New screen". How should i approach this to have the drawer in this activity as well?
I don't want to have too much boiler code.
It already has problems on android 4.2.2, I can only imagine now how this modifications will affect performance. 
I need to understand what is best solution, have no experience with this. All I want is ideas and maybe get some know-how on this pattern so i don't cause memory leaks and don't duplicate code.

Thank you for your time.

[image]

Comment: Can't you create one child fragment for "New Screen" ? instead of creating new activity..

Comment: this should be problematic when i receive a notification and need to open that specific screen that now is a fragment, so should be attached to an activity. I have a lot of logic in main activity, rendering will take forever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1-I would suggest to create a Base Activity which will further extends your ActionBarActivity.

2-activity_sliding_drawer layout file for this activity will contains a main_container for adding fragments and DrawerLayout:-

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_container"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white">
     </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/slidingMenuFragment"
    android:name="om.ooredoo.fragments.SlidingMenuFragment"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/slidingmenu__parent_width"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" />
```

3- Then inside base activity, we will have all basic functions for add and replace fragments and also 2 function which will handle visibility for drawer menu icon, i.e `lockDrawerMenu()` & `unlockDrawerMenu()`.

4- Put the following code inside your base activity (AbstractActivity in my case):-

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
private boolean bSupportActionBar = true;
private boolean mSlidingMenuLocked = false;
private BackPressListener mBackPressListener;
private String title;


boolean ismSlidingMenuLocked() {
    return mSlidingMenuLocked;
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_drawer);

    if (bSupportActionBar) {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerLayout.setScrimColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.drawer_open, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.drawer_close // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                if (getSupportActionBar().getTitle().equals(getString(R.string.app_name)))
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                title = (String) getSupportActionBar().getTitle();
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));

                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        unlockDrawerMenu();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    setSupportProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mHandler != null) {
        mHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        mHandler = null;
    }
}


public void addNewFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("AbstractActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

public void addNewFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment, boolean animation) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, 0);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment, fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("AbstractActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}

public void addNewBottomFragmentWithBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_up_anim, 0);
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.bottom_container, fragment)
                .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName())
                .commit();
    } else {
        Log.e("AbstractActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}






public void replaceAndClearBackStack(Fragment fragment) {
    //clear backStack
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(fragment.getClass().getSimpleName());
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    if (bSupportActionBar)
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggles
    if (bSupportActionBar)
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}


public void lockDrawerMenu() {
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
    if (bSupportActionBar) {
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
    }
    mSlidingMenuLocked = true;


}

public void unlockDrawerMenu() {
    ((DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout)).setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    mSlidingMenuLocked = false;
    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
    if (!ismSlidingMenuLocked() && mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }

    // Handle action bar actions click
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            if (ismSlidingMenuLocked()) {
                onBackPressed();
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        default: {
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}

public BackPressListener getBackPressListener() {
    return mBackPressListener;
}

public void setBackPressListener(BackPressListener mBackPressListener) {
    this.mBackPressListener = mBackPressListener;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().size() > 0) {
        for (Fragment frag : getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            if (frag != null && frag.isAdded() && frag instanceof AbstractParentFragment) {
                if (frag.getChildFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                    frag.getChildFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    return;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    if (mBackPressListener != null) {
        if (mBackPressListener.onBackPress())
            return;
    } else {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {
            this.finish();
            return;
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

void supportActionBar(boolean support) {
    bSupportActionBar = support;
}}
```

5- Now create a Sliding drawer activity which extends your base activity and launch your main fragment inside this main fragment open your other fragments basics of item clicked in sliding drawer.
Now you have two function to handle sliding drawer if sliding drawer icon is  visible then it works on the basics of item clicked else it will a normal fragment with action bar.

Hope this will help you. !!!

Comment: I will try. Thank you. Will get back to you.